# send multiple files as mail though mailx command

Tags: scripting, mailx

I have 3 file names present inside a .txt file

I have to read all file names and send them as a attachment in a mail.

Example:

test.txt  - (file name)

```
-query1.dat

-query2.dat

-query3.dat
```

I have to read test.txt file and get all those query*.dat files and send a mail with all those files as attachment using mailx command.

I have this code:

```
while read line
do

    mailx -a ${line} -s "files" ${mail_from} << EOM

    Hi, Sent files

    EOM

done<test.txt
```

It sends each file seperately in a seperate mail.

I need to send all these files in a single mail.

How to do that?

Comment: zip them first?

Comment: hey @ArtemS.Tashkinov.. can u explain further?

Comment: `zip files.zip file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt`, send files.zip

Comment: Thank you @ArtemS.Tashkinov

Answer (score 1):

You can attach multiple `-a file` in the same invocation of `mailx`.

```
while read pj ; do
    attach+=( -a "$pj" )
done < test.txt

mailx "${attach[@]}" -s "files" ${mail_from} << EOM

    Hi, Sent files

EOM
```

- `attach+=( -a "$pj")` append 2 elements to the array
- `"${attach[@]}"` expand each element of the array in separated values, not broken by space in values.